# Countdown parameter with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a js function , that counts down to 0 from a parameter s.
and displays that at a `<p>` with the **id** = **count** , the function starts via `onclick="countdown(60)"` from a Button , but somehow it doesn t work. 
Someone has a idea why ? 
Thank you for your help.

```
var count ;
function countdown(s){
    count = s ; 
    while (s > 0) {
        document.getElementById("count").innerText = count ;
    setTimeout(tick(), 1000) ; 
    }
     document.getElementById("count").innerText = "ready" ;

}
function tick (){
    count -- ; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points:

- Your while loop will stack the `setInterval` calls immediately, and therefore they'll all fire after 1 second.
- Calling `setTimeout(tick()..` will execute the `tick` function immediately

See the below as an alternative:

```js
var countdown = function(s){
 
 var c = document.getElementById("count");
  
 var tick = function(){    
    c.innerText = s;
 };
  
 var ready = function(){
   clearInterval(i);
   c.innerText = "ready";
 };
 
 tick();
 
 var i = setInterval(function(){
  (s>0) ? function(){ s--;tick(); }() : ready();
 }, 1000);
 
 
}

countdown(10);
```

```html
<div id="count"></div>
```

Comment: I don t understand the code ... but it works , thank you

Comment: @ElBiasto Updated to include the `ready` part. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: (s>0) ? function(){ s--;tick(); }() : ready(); I never saw that , Is it like if s>0 { tick() } else { c="ready" }

Comment: @ElBiasto Yes that's right :) It's a short-hand `if` statement. E.g `if (1===1) { return true; } else { return false; }` is the same as `return(1===1)?true:false;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var count;
function countdown(s){
 s = count;      // reverse this line and it should work
    while (s > 0) {
        document.getElementById("count").innerText = count ;
      setTimeout(tick(), 1000); 
    }
    document.getElementById("count").innerText = "ready" ;

}
function tick (){
    count -- ; 
}
```

Comment: haha thank you :D that was such a dumb mistake ^^ I don t know why I didn t find it ;D